# comparing utf8 encoding string in sql in DB2?

Tags: sql, string, utf-8, db2, string-comparison

I have a problem in comparing two persian string in sql DB2 format in my java app.I want to count the number of rows that has the same content but with this query the result is 0 while it's not true :

```
SELECT COUNT(G.GROUPCODE) as PO_GROUPCOUNT
FROM   MISSHMA.MTPGROUPS G
 where REPLACE(Cast(rtrim(ltrim(G.GROUPDESC)) As Varchar(200) ccsid 1252),' ','') ='تست 1'   WITH UR
```

Comment: Side note: doing all that to a column will invalidate the use of indicies (query would be slow).

Comment: It's ok,I've just want to know is there any same string in my db or not. is there any other way for doing this?

Comment: Well, we're going to need a lot more information, because most systems don't deal with UTF-8 encoding by default; java actually uses UTF-16 for its string type, for example.  So, what are you passing from Java - plain string, array of byte?  What's the type of the data in DB2?  How are you talking to DB2, are you using an ORM?  What does your calling code look like?

Comment: I'm sorry of replying late,

Comment: My data type in table is varchar and it's storing in database as byte codes. It's not ORM and using JDBC connection.

Comment: 1) This sort of thing is supposed to go in the question.  2) It would help a lot if you showed the table definition, some sample data, and a bit of the calling Java code, too.